# Slice a dense tensor into ragged flat values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2D dense tensor and a vector of lengths, which are the first K elements of each row I would like to select:

```py
x = tf.constant([
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
])

seq_len = tf.constant([3, 3, 2, 5])
```

Desired output would be:

```
tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

I have tried going dense->ragged to get the flat values, but this does not work:

```py
>>> tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_lengths(x, seq_len)

InvalidArgumentError: Arguments to _from_row_partition do not form a valid RaggedTensor
Condition x == y did not hold.
First 1 elements of x:
[13]
First 1 elements of y:
[4]
```

I cannot go dense -> sparse either since there is a zero I would like to keep in the output. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking `tf.RaggedTensor`  or `tf.constant` in output ? If you are looking for ragged tensor please try 'tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x, padding=0)`

Comment: @TFer2 that was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! If you want to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice a dense tensor to ragged tensor as shown below

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
])

seq_len = tf.constant([3, 3, 2, 5])
```

To achieve desired output, you can use args `padding`

```
tf.RaggedTensor.from_tensor(x, padding=0)
```

Output:

```
<tf.RaggedTensor [[1, 1, 1], [2, 0, 2], [1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1]]>
```